# VBA copy page range from word document, and paste values matching format

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a code that copies the page range of a document, creates a new sheet and paste the data there. However, it is not matching the format of the word doc being copied. See code below.

I tried changing `selection.copy` to `selection.copyFormat`, but it is simply copying the actual VBA code, and pasting it in the word document.

```
Sub selectpages()
  Dim rgePages As Range
  ThisDocument.Activate

  Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=196
  Set rgePages = Selection.Range
  Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=207
  rgePages.End = Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.End
  rgePages.Select
  Selection.Copy
  Set objNewDoc = Documents.Add
  Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
  objNewDoc.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\GP8535\Desktop\Word Doc" & "\" & "SB 59_test" & ".docx"
  objNewDoc.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you think this is doing ->wdFormatPlainText.  You should also investigate the .FormattedText property as in  'objNewDoc.content.formattedtext=rgePages.formattedtext'

Comment: As @Freeflow mention please check your parameter `wdFormatPlainText`. There are other possible types you can use for example `wdFormatOriginalFormatting`. More information you find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrecoverytype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to activate or select anything. Try:

```
Sub CopyContent()
  Dim Rng As Range, RngTmp As Range, wdDoc As Document
  With ThisDocument
    Set Rng = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=196)
    Set RngTmp = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=207)
    Set RngTmp = RngTmp.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page")
    Rng.End = RngTmp.End: Set RngTmp = Nothing
  End With
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    Rng.Copy
    .Range.Characters.Last.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    .SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\GP8535\Desktop\Word Doc\SB 59_test.docx"
    .Close
  End With
  Set Rng = Nothing
End Sub
```